# Joining data from two tables with different WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to perform a variety of Joins / Unions on two separate tables to combine my results into a single table. First I will share what I have and what I need, then I'll share my current non-working solution.

What I have:

- Each table consists of a list of operations performed, each operation has a `opPatient` (all patients have had multiple operations), `opClassification` (1, 2, 3 or 4), `opDate`, `opPrice`.
- A `Start` and `End` date of the query.

What I need:

To produce a single table with:

- A list of all distinct `opPatients`
- For each patient:

  - Total `opprice` of all operations
  - Total `opPrice` of all operations with classification of 4 (Classification 4 is only in `table2`)
  - Total number of all operations
  - Total number of operations with a classification of 3
  - Total number of operations with a classification of 2
- All of the above `WHERE opDate >= @StartDate AND opDate <= EndDate`

Current solution (not working obviously)

- Sets the `start` and `end` dates (no errors here)

  ```
  SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(Day, @Date)-1), @Date);    
  SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, (DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDate)));

  SELECT
     Operation = (SELECT DISTINCT operation FROM table1
                  UNION
                  SELECT DISTINCT operation FROM table2),
     TotalPrice = CAST(opPrice) AS MONEY),
     TotalOps = COUNT(*),
     opC4 = COUNT(CASE
              WHEN opClassification = 4 THEN 1 
              ELSE Null                                  
              END) 
              WHERE opDate <= @EndDate AND opDate >= @StartDate 
              FROM table2,            
     opC3 = COUNT (CASE WHEN opClassification = 3 THEN 1 ELSE Null END),
     opC2 = COUNT (CASE WHEN opClassification = 2 THEN 1 ELSE Null END)
   FROM 
      table1, table2
   WHERE 
       table1.opDate <= @EndDate AND table1.opDate >= @StartDate 
   ORDER BY 
       Operation
  ```

All help, tips and pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!
Sincerely, A nooby coder.

Comment: Hi, Just some extra information: For operation, the data must be retrieved between StartDate and Enddate as well. Thank you all so much for taking your time to view + answer! I really appreciate it ^.^

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements, seems this is what you need.

```
SELECT opPatient
, SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) opC1
, SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) opC2
, SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) opC3
, SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) opC4
, SUM(opPrice) AS TotalPrice
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Table2
) AS NewTable
WHERE opDate >= @StartDate AND opDate <= @EndDate 
GROUP BY opPatient
```

Comment: Hi Prasanna,
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(Day, @Date)-1), @Date);
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, (DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDate)));  

SELECT opPatient, 
    -- Totals
    COUNT(opPrice) AS OpsTotal, 
    SUM(opPrice) AS PriceTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opDate >= @StartDate AND opDate <= EndDate THEN opPrice END) AS PriceThisMonth,
    -- Op 4
    SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 4 THEN 1 END) AS OpsOp4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 4 THEN opPrice END) AS PriceOp4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 4 AND opDate >= @StartDate AND opDate <= EndDate THEN opPrice END) AS Op4PriceThisMonth,
    -- Op 3
    SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 3 THEN 1 END) AS OpsOp4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 3 THEN opPrice END) AS PriceOp4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 3 AND opDate >= @StartDate AND opDate <= EndDate THEN opPrice END) AS Op4PriceThisMonth,
    -- Op 2
    SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 2 THEN 1 END) AS OpsOp4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 2 THEN opPrice END) AS PriceOp4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opClassification = 2 AND opDate >= @StartDate AND opDate <= EndDate THEN opPrice END) AS Op4PriceThisMonth,

FROM (
    SELECT opPatient, opClassification, opDate, opPrice
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT opPatient, opClassification, opDate, opPrice
    FROM Table1
)
GROUP BY opPatient
```